# How to use Entity Framework to combine nested cross join and left join

Tags: join, .net-core

I want to write the following code with Entity Framework.

```
select* from LocaleStringResource as locale 
cross join Language language
left join LocaleStringResourceLanguage localeLang 
on locale.Id = localeLang.RecordId and 
language.ID = localeLang.LanguageId
```

How can I do this?

Comment: is this LINQ to SQL, what else have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assumed some information because you don't give us enough information about the entities. I guess that you trying to do this. Try this en let us know if it's the right approach.

```
var query =  (from locale in _context.LocaleStringResource 
                 from language in _context.Language 
                 join localeLangBefLJ in _context.LocaleStringResourceLanguage on new { field1 = locale.Id, field2 = language.ID } equals new { field1 = localeLangBefLJ.RecordId, field2 = localeLangBefLJ.LanguageId }
                      into localeLang 
                 from x in localeLang.DefaultIfEmpty()
                 select new
                 {
                     locale,
                     language, 
                     x
                 })
```